# Can't access to hard drive to create partition in Gparted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

I want to create a swap partition in `/dev/sdb`, but in Gparted there only `/dev/sdb`. I can't use any option like move/resize or access to `sdb1`, `sdb2`,..

[image]

In terminal, `sudo fdisk -l` showed:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 10BB5600-3421-4356-B61B-37A1D7A59ACE

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1    1161216 179920895 178759680  85.2G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2  179920896 234440427  54519532    26G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3       2048   1160250   1158203 565.5M EFI System

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

And this is my `/dev/sda` using Gparted, looks normal:

[image]

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.1.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The ISO9660 file system of `/dev/sdb` means it is an image of a DVD or it is a DVD.

Comment: I think there's something wrong. `sdb` is my ssd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be multiple (some incorrect) file system signatures on disk device sdb.  This can happen if an ISO image was copied to the drive in the past, but was not completely removed before the drive was partitioned.

To learn more run the following two commands:

```
sudo blkid /dev/sdb

sudo wipefs --no-act /dev/sdb
```

If the drive is supposed to be partitioned as shown by the `fdisk` command, and if an **ISO** signature is discovered but not supposed to be there then you can use the `wipefs` command with the appropriate options to remove just the **ISO** signature.

**NOTE:  To avoid loss of important data, be sure to have a backup of your data before editing partitions and wiping out file system signatures.**